# VLOOKUP for multiple conditions which references inn different sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In SheetB: A list of **Weapon Name** with **Type**, **Weapon Rarity**, **Class 1** and **Class 2** (there are 2 classes can wear a same set)

In SheetC: A database with **Hero Name** and their **Classes**

In SheetA: I have a list of **Hero Name** with provided their **Weapon Rarity**.  Now I need to fill the matched values for three columns: **Weapon Name**, **Head Name**, **Armor Name**.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12uDJXmqhKblClssdTEewgcYup3O1MJ389VKf670t5sM/edit#gid=1639375076

The problems are:

- Class 1 and 2 in SheetB and are not the first column
- Hero Name is in SheetC
- And there are multiple conditions:  Weapon Rarity, Weapon Type, Class, etc.

Comment: Have you actually tried to do a ```VLOOKUP```? With ```VLOOKUP```s you can search for multiple criteria, [check this post](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/vlookup-multiple-criteria/) for more info regarding this. Also, **what exactly are you trying to search for? What is the criteria you are planning to use and what expected output you want?**

Comment: VLOOKUP cannot search if the Index is on the left of the key. For other questions, I mentioned clearly in the question and there is also the example sheet above.

Comment: Hi ! In your case, are you exclusively trying to achieve this with a formula (for example ```VLOOKUP```), or are you okay with using a script?

Comment: Hi. Just Formula. I managed to use INDEX MATCH for this.

Comment: Did ```INDEX MATCH``` solved your issue? If so, could you please post it as an answer to this question so that everyone facing the same problem can easily see the solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution for this by using INDEX MATCH:

> =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SheetB!$A$2:$A$19,MATCH(CONCATENATE($B2,VLOOKUP($A2,SheetC!$A$2:$B$10,2,0),"Weapon"),SheetB!$C$2:$C$19&SheetB!$D$2:$D$19&SheetB!$B$2:$B$19,0),)),
>   (ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SheetB!$A$2:$A$19,MATCH(CONCATENATE($B2,VLOOKUP($A2,SheetC!$A$2:$B$10,2,0),"Weapon"),SheetB!$C$2:$C$19&SheetB!$E$2:$E$19&SheetB!$B$2:$B$19,0),))))

Updated sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12uDJXmqhKblClssdTEewgcYup3O1MJ389VKf670t5sM/edit#gid=1639375076